# React Native - How to send objects in renderItem?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm receiving data from api like this:

```
{
    "isTrue": true,
    "data1": {
        "username": "user1",
        "images": [
            "image1.jpg",
            "image2.jpg"
        ]
    },
    "data2": {
        "location": "new york",
        "age": "80"
    }
}
```

and setting it in my state as details.

I want to display data in flatlist, so I do this:

```
<FlatList
    data={state.details}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        <Details item={item} />;
    }}
></FlatList>
```

in my  component I render data like:

```
export default Details = ({item}) => {

  return item
    ? Object.values(item).map(value => {
        <Text>{value.data1?.username}</Text>;
      })
    : null;
};
```

Why don't the items render?

Comment: `renderItem` of `FlatList` is accept an array so you need to convert your object to array first

Comment: I tried by doing: Objects.values(state.details), and it does convert to array but it still doesnt return in other component

Comment: first check if the array is right, and check the `item` props in your `Details` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure u pass `Array` to [flat list](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

like  :

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
    title: "First Item",
  },
  {
    id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
    title: "Second Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
    title: "Third Item",
  },
];
```

flat list will do for loop for you, so u don't need to  `values(item).map` you can do:

```
export default Details = ({item}) => {

  return 
    <View> 
        <Text>{item.isTrue}</Text>
        <Text>{item.data1.username}</Text>
    </View>
};
```

change

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
        <Details item={item} />;
    }}
```

to

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
       return <Details item={item} />;
    }}
```

or

```
renderItem={({item}) =>  (<Details item={item} />)}
```

finally don't forget to add `<View></View>` as parent for `<Text><Text>`

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I'm able to pass it to the Details component and log items but now It's not letting me render the items. I updated the question with the code for the component, i'd appreciate it if you looked at it.

Comment: answer updated  , check